# MSDOS style Input field in python

Tags: python, input-field

I'm hoping someone can help...
I'm looking to create an input field that goes over dots in PYTHON...
heres and example in MSDOS

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/3b/Norton_Utilities_6.01_UI.png
Please look at the top input field file name, this is something similar I'm hoping to get help with...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can't you just initialize the field with a bunch of dots?

Comment: That won't work because it will either all go away when the user starts typing or the user will end up actually submitting a string of dots following the real text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried so far?

You can use [Python's `input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input) to receive input, however that won't write over dots.
If you wanted to create an interface similar to the linked screenshot, you will need to use the [curses module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses).

Comment: ive been researching but i haven't had much luck :( , thank you for the swift help! Do you have an idea of a summary of code that would needed?

Comment: I haven't used the curses module yet but it looks like there's a [good tutorial in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#curses-howto) and another on [Tuxradar](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/code-project-build-ncurses-ui-python).